# *ngFor is not destroying components as expected

Tags: angular

I am reading [this](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5) small article. Article says:

> If you need at some point to change the data in the collection, for example as a result of an API request, we have a problem because Angular can’t keep track of items in the collection and has no knowledge of which items have been removed or added.
>
> As a result, **Angular needs to remove all the DOM elements** that associated with the data and create them again.
>
> **Note:** when I’m saying “change the data” I’m referring to replace the collection with new objects and not keeping the same reference.

I tried to check if this. My code is following ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vanwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)):

**html**

```
 <button (click)="changeObjItems()">Change Items array</button>
 <app-item *ngFor="let i of objItems" [val]="i.item.id"></app-item>//line 2
```

**Typescript**

```
   objItems = [
      {item: {id:1}},
      {item: {id:1}},
      {item: {id:1}},
      {item: {id:1}}
    ];

  changeObjItems(){
     this.objItems[3] = {item:{id: Math.random()}};
     this.objItems = [...this.objItems];//shallow clone
  }
```

So basically in line 2, I am iterating over an array nested object (`objItems`) and created a new component (`app-item`) on each iteration. Later I am changing the data of the array (by `changeObjItems()`) and checking if all the previous components are destroyed by logging into onDestroy of `app-item`.

However, after running `changeObjItems()`, console shows that *ngFor is only destroying the component for which data has been changed. But as per article, I was expecting all components to be destroyed.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I see the issue perhaps I have less knowledge in this section then. Let me check , for the time I will delete my answer.

Comment: when you do `this.objItems = [...this.objItems];//shallow clone`, angular knows that the first 3 items have not changed, so it does not re-render corresponding elements in DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *clone* all objects in the array to trick change detection in ngFor.

```
 this.objItems[3] = {item:{id: Math.random()}};
 this.objItems = this.objItems.map(obj => {...obj});
```

Cloning/slicing the array itself has no effect, because ngFor is tracking the contents of the array against each DOM element. It remembers what value was previously used for DOM element, and if that value has not changed it will not recreate the DOM element.

That can be a problem for items that mutate but represent the same data, and that is why ngFor has the trackBy callback which allows you to change what value is remembered for DOM elements.

Comment: I also think so. Does this mean that quote from the article is wrong?

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services when in doubt read the official documentation. Angular clearly says "Angular uses object identity to track insertions and deletions within the iterator and reproduce those changes in the DOM". https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation